# Using Eval to play a flash video.

Tags: javascript, asp.net, database, eval, flv

Trying to use Eval to play a flv from a database that is in a table, there can be multiple videos so I figured just list them out and have its path be defined.

```
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="FLAlink" runat="server" NavigateUrl='javascript:playFlash("<%# Eval("link") + "flv" %>");'><asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl="fla-button.png" /></asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

Is so far what I got. Problem is that its not playing in the embed video section of my page. Not exactly sure what I'm missing. If you have any suggestions on how to make it better I will take that too.

Comment: Please show the OUTPUT of your code, not your code itself.

Comment: The output is nothing. It doesn't play in the video screen or open up the download option or anything. It shows that the link should open javascript:playFlash("<%#%20Eval("link")%20+%20"flv"%20%>"); but it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your quotes are a bit messed up, not sure what you are going for exactly, but try this:

```
'javascript:playFlash("<%# "+Eval("link") + "flv %>");'
```